# Firefox import bookmarks/settings dialog

Tags: firefox

I've been very unhappy with Chrome off late, and I want to move back to firefox. The only problem is I have a load of bookmarks and saved passwords in Chrome.
I remember firefox showing me a dialog to import bookmarks and passwords from chrome the first time I started it, but I just can't seem to find it anywhere now. I even tried googling for it, but no one seems to address the issue.
I am sure there is something very simple I am missing here.

Comment: Alt+B, show all bookmarks, import and backup, import data from another browser.

Comment: @vasa1 there it is! However, it said "No browser found".. It doesn't work with Chromium? Anyway, I use google chrome in my office desktop, and I will try importing the data from there.

Comment: Same here. I have Firefox 22, Chrome 28 and Chromium 25. Firefox only sees Chrome to import from. Strange!

Comment: @vasa1 i just tried it.. it worked, but a little disappointed that it didn't import my passwords. Oh well. Anyway, you answered my question, so you can put it down as an answer and I can accept it, and close this question.

Comment: I'll keep a lookout about importing passwords and ping you if I come across anything. I use both Firefox and Chrome. Have you posted anywhere about your difficulties with Chrome?

Comment: BTW, https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589589 indicates that importing passwords is a work in progress :(

Comment: @vasa1 ah.. I think I am just going to use an external password manager to export and import passwords for now. I hear lastpass extension/plugin for chrome and firefox can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can import bookmarks from Chrome (but apparently not from Chromium!). To do so, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to open the bookmarks window, click on `Import and backup`, and then on `import data from another browser`. You should see `Chrome` listed.