# Import bookmarks into Firefox from Windows/Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I've been using Chrome on Windows for years now, but that system won't boot anymore.  I have a large collection of bookmarks that I'd like to transfer to Firefox on my new Ubuntu installation.  The instructions I find online like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/309331/25325) assume Chrome is installed on Ubuntu as well, and apparently at that point it's a simple and painless process.

I have access to the Windows disk, and have located the Chrome bookmark file.  When you try to import a file into Firefox, all it lets you import is a HTML file.  The file I have is JSON and Firefox doesn't understand it.

I've considered installing Chrome just to copy the bookmarks, but that seems like overkill.  I can't help but wonder if there isn't a simpler and more direct way.  If you know what that is please leave an answer.

Edit: I tried copying the bookmark file to the location Chrome is supposed to use on Linux, hoping that would trick Firefox into believing that Chrome was installed and allowing the simple import to work.  Didn't help.

Comment: Maybe it will work when you try to load the JSON file as a backup copy of bookmarks in Firefox (Manage bookmarks -> Import and backup -> Restore -> Choose file) ? I'm not sure if the formats are compatible, but maybe?

Comment: @raj thanks for the suggestion.  I tried it, it didn't complain but it didn't give me any new bookmarks either.

Comment: So it seems there's no other option than install Chrome to import these bookmarks. Or try to find a script (maybe someone has already written such a thing) that is able to read and convert this JSON file from Chrome.

Comment: @raj I'm trying to write my own Python script to convert the JSON to HTML that can be imported.  If I'm successful I'll post it here as an answer.  Much more work than just installing Chrome, but ultimately more satisfying.